# why does not PHP include work?

Tags: php, variables, include, require

I have a strange problem. I have one file **index.php** in the root, and 2 files **include** directory inside the root.

> root > index.php , include
>    include > config.php , db.php

In **include/db.php** I defined MySQL connection parameters like this:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname   = 'mydb';
```

Then I have included this file inside **include/config.php** :

```
include 'db.php';
```

And finally, I've included **include/config.php** inside **index.php**.
The problem I have is I have not access to database variables when I run **index.php**. They are only available if I run **include/config.php**. But I expected I must have all defined variables inside these 2 files when I included them in **index.php**.

What is the problem ?

Comment: `index.php` includes `config.php` includes `db.php` — Is that correct? Also, how do you know you don't have access to the variables? What does `print_r(get_defined_vars());` output?

Comment: Is it really the `include()` that does not work? You should get an error if that is the case!

Comment: How have you tried to include config.php inside index.php? Syntax?

Comment: Are you getting any error/ Warning ? Did you check echoing variables in index.php file ?

Comment: @AmalMurali, yes that's it. I put `echo $hostname;` after including db.php . When I run index.php , nothing appears, but when I run include/config.php , it shows mydb

Comment: @KanishkDudeja, it has a common syntax. `include 'include/config.php';`

Comment: @Theorem, no. I don't see any error. Nothing appears in the page.

Comment: @AmalMurali, `print_r(get_defined_vars())` does not contain `dbname` and other variables.

Comment: Okay try using require in index.php page instead of include, check if you get path error.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi add this at the top of index.php and then show us the error `error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @Theorem, I did it too. No error occurred

Comment: If you are getting blank screen you have to set error reporting On.

Comment: Did you `print_r($GLOBALS);` and not sign of your vars there? Do what @zzlalani said by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",1);` in the top of your `index.php`

Comment: I just tested locally and it works fine. I can only assume you're making a spelling mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Theorem, I did it. Now errors say `Notice: Undefined variable: dbname in ...`

Comment: @MohammadSaberi either the variables are may be defined in some function or class or you are trying to access them within some function or class, can you show us complete code?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi can you show us the complete code ?

Comment: I found out something. If I write `include 'include/db.php';` in config.php , I can access to database variables inside index.php

Answer (score 0):

if you have included config.php in index.php and db.php in config.php. Then index.php should be: `include 'include/config.php';` and config.php should be: `include 'include/db.php';`